# Crosswalk-Project version code issue?

Tags: android, google-play, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I have android app with version code "20100000" and version name "1.0.0" in google play store.

I want to update my new app version but I have a problem about version code.

I have a error "20100000 version code already exist" when update my app.I changed my version code all things but I see always this error.Anybody know how I can change version code ?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "short_name": "",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "any",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "xwalk_app_version": "3.5",
  "xwalk_command_line": "",
  "xwalk_package_id": "",
  "xwalk_target_platforms": [
    "android"
  ],
  "xwalk_android_animatable_view": true,
  "xwalk_android_keep_screen_on": false,
  "xwalk_android_permissions": [
    "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    "ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
    "INTERNET"
  ],
  "xwalk_windows_update_id": "",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon.png",
      "sizes": "72x72"
    }
  ]
}
```

**CMD**

```
python make_apk.py --package=x --manifest=x/manifest.json --arch=arm --keystore-path=x\crosswalk-17.46.448.10\x.keystore --keystore-alias=x --keystore-passcode=xxx
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `--app-versionCode` command with make_apk.py.

`--app-versionCode=APP_VERSIONCODE
                        An integer corresponding to the android:versionCode
                        attribute of the Android App Manifest. If specified,
                        the value of the "--app-version" option is not used to
                        set the value of the android:versionCode attribute.`